# Hiding Window with Powershell script running in the background

Tags: powershell, background, hidden

I am facing some trouble with a powershell script with running in the background. Following is my command. `>Powershell.exe -File C:\testFolder\script.ps1 -WindowStyle Hidden`. Nothing happens. The script doesn't work. The script works fine running with Windows Powershell ISE.

Following is my powershell script.

```
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = "C:\ProgramData\"
$watcher.Filter = "output.txt";
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true 
$args = “$Server $FolderName”
$command = “cmd /C cscript .\VBScript.vbs $args”

$action = { $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
            $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
            $logline = "$(Get-Date), $changeType, $path"
            Add-content "D:\log.txt" -value $logline
           invoke-expression $command
Write-Host "Test2"
          }    
Write-Host "Test"
$created = Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action
$changed = Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Changed" -Action $action
$deleted = Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Deleted" -Action $action
$renamed = Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Renamed" -Action $action
```

Executing the powershell script in the Windows Powershell ISE outputs both (Test and Test2), while from the command prompt outputs just "Test".

Comment: Are you sure your executionpolicy allows running the script? Try `Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -WindowStyle Hidden -File C:\testFolder\script.ps1`

Comment: Does it work if you omit the `-WindowStyle Hidden` parameter?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't. I have checked the powershell.exe path in the environment variables. But just doesn't seem to work. Does not give any error either.

Comment: @NeelDeveloper Replace the `-WindowStyle hidden` with `-NoExit` switch so Powershell window won't close. Add some `write-host` statements to the script to see what happens. This sounds like you got an UAC problem. Further analysis would benefit from a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Oh. Sorry, I needed to add `while ($true) {}`

Answer (score 0):

Oh. I needed to add `while ($true) {}` at the end.